# Проблема с наполнением контекстного меню

Tags: windows-11

Не могу ничего создать кроме того, что на скрине. В чем может быть проблема и можно ли это как то исправить? Особенно меня интересует создание обычного текстового файла.

[image]

Comment: Зайдите в блокнот или в ворд и создавайте на здоровье. А еще лучше откройте учебник по информатике за 7 класс и почитайте.

Comment: @Глеб когда писали учебник по информатике для 7 класса, никакого windows 11 и подавно не было!

Comment: @Глеб Вы такой остроумный!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем скачал блокнот из Microsoft Store и это решило мою проблему. По умолчанию блокнота у меня не было =)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы добавить пункт в контекстное меню, нужно править реестр, что туда внести, можно найти в поисковых системах, но если нет понятия как это работает, лучше туда не лезть, так как после неудачной правки компьютер может перестать работать.
 Еще один вариант добавить блокнот в панель задач.
 Можно добавить ярлык, на рабочий стол, назначить "горячие клавиши" и запускать с клавиатуры, но я попробовал, запуск происходит секунд через 5.